# Manipulating a class to alter another class while using CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv, class

In ruby, if I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
make,model,color,doors
dodge,charger,black,4
ford,focus,blue,5
nissan,350z,black,2
mazda,miata,white,2
honda,civid,brown,4
corvette,stingray,red,2
ford,fiesta,blue,5
bmw,m4,black,2
audi,a5,blue,2
subaru,brz,black,2
lexus,rc,black,2
```

If I run my code and choose "doors" for my "wanted_attribute" and "2" for my "value" (my gets.chomp), it outputs all the cars that only have 2 doors from the CSV file:

```
make: nissan, model: 350z, color: black, doors: 2
make: mazda, model: miata, color: white, doors: 2
make: corvette, model: stingray, color: red, doors: 2
make: bmw, model: m4, color: black, doors: 2
make: audi, model: a5, color: blue, doors: 2
make: subaru, model: brz, color: black, doors: 2
make: lexus, model: rc, color: black, doors: 2
```

How would I be able to condense this even more and make it that from this group of, doors 2, it condenses more into, color black, for example this should be the final output (outputs only color black cars):

```
make: nissan, model: 350z, color: black, doors: 2
make: bmw, model: m4, color: black, doors: 2
make: subaru, model: brz, color: black, doors: 2
make: lexus, model: rc, color: black, doors: 2
```

This is my current code:

```
require "csv"

class Car
    attr_accessor :make, :model, :color, :doors

    def initialize(make, model, color, doors)
        @make, @model, @color, @doors = make, model, color, doors
    end

    def to_s
        "make: #{self.make}, model: #{self.model}, color: #{self.color}, doors: #{self.doors}"
    end
end

cars = CSV.read("so.csv").map{|car| Car.new(car[0], car[1], car[2], car[3])}

print "Select attribute: "
wanted_attribute = gets.chomp
print "Select value: "
value = gets.chomp

wanted_cars = cars.select{|car| car.instance_variable_get("@#{wanted_attribute}") == value}
puts wanted_cars
```

please comment code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add multiple conditions inside your main logic:

```
print "Select color attribute: "
wanted_color_attribute = gets.chomp
print "Select color: "
color = gets.chomp

wanted_cars = cars.select{|car| car.instance_variable_get("@#{wanted_attribute}") == value && car.instance_variable_get("@#{wanted_color_attribute}") == "#{color}"}
```

Hope it helps!